# How to pass multiple blob parameters to SQLite statement?

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite

This code throws exception on second sqlite3_bind_blob:

```
sqlite3_stmt* _stmt;
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("update logins set password_value=?, possible_usernames=?, form_data=? "
    "where origin_url='%q' and username_element='%q' and username_value='%q' and password_element='%q' and signon_realm='%q'",
    sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4));
sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &_stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 1, DataOut5.pbData, DataOut5.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 2, DataOut6.pbData, DataOut6.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 3, DataOut7.pbData, DataOut7.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_step(_stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(_stmt);
sqlite3_free(sql);
```

This code completes successfuly:

```
sqlite3_stmt* _stmt;
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("update logins set password_value=? "//, possible_usernames=?, form_data=? "
    "where origin_url='%q' and username_element='%q' and username_value='%q' and password_element='%q' and signon_realm='%q'",
    sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4));
sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &_stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 1, DataOut5.pbData, DataOut5.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
//sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 2, DataOut6.pbData, DataOut6.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
//sqlite3_bind_blob(_stmt, 3, DataOut7.pbData, DataOut7.cbData, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_step(_stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(_stmt);
sqlite3_free(sql);
```

Why?

Comment: I guess would be, there's something wrong with `DataOut6` and `DataOut7`. Dangling pointers, or something along these lines.

Comment: Why do you assume that the calls to `sqlite3_prepare` and `sqlite3_step` succeed?

Comment: I have compiled and run the second example successfuly - resulted as expected.